# How to create a variable parameter in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I am new in NetLogo and I have a question, if anyone can help me I would appreciate it :)

I have a 90x90 world. Each patch in the world has a resource value (resource variable that has the smallest value from 10000 to infinity, integers). In the world I have 60 turtles.

I would like every tick to have a parameter that affects the world as a whole. A value drawn from 0 to 1 that will be multiplied in the resource variable

And I would like to compute that:

```
the resource of the turtles is = the value of the patch * (the parameter that affects the whole world) - its metabolism
```

But, I'm not able to implement some details above.
I tried to remove the file in .txt. But, I don't know how to do that. For example assigning a value to each patch. Sorry...

```
globals [ edge-size ]
turtles-own [ metabolism resource-turtle ]
patches-own [ resources ]

to setup
 ca
  reset-ticks
  set edge-size 90
  set-patch-size 12
  ask n-of 60 patches  [sprout 1 [ setup-turtles ] ]
  setup-patches
end

to setup-patches
  file-open "resource.txt"
  foreach sort patches [ p ->
    ask p [
      set resources file-read       
    ]
  ]
  file-close
end
 
to setup-turtles
  set metabolism 4
  set resource-turtle [ resources ] of patch-here
end 

to go  
  ask turtles [
    right random 360
    fd 1
    turtle-eat
    reproduction
    if ticks <= 10 [ die ]
  ]
  parameter-world
  
  tick  
end

to turtle-eat   
 set resource-turtle (resources - metabolism )   ;; Here it doesn't do exactly what I want it to do: the resource of the turtles is = the value of the patch * (the parameter that affects the whole world) - its metabolism
end

to reproduction
  if (resource-turtle > 5) [
    hatch 1
  ]
end

to parameter-world ;; And the probability parameter leaves the patch with fractional values... Is this the best way to implement this probability?
  ask patches [
      let prob random-float 2
     set resources resources * prob
   ]
end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: (1) In your formula and in the code happen two different things: in the formula the resource of the patch stays the same. In the code, the resource is reduced with every simulation step, because you `set resources resources * prob` . What behavior do you want to have?

(2) Also, I don't understand, if you want the parameter/prob to be the same for all patches in one step (for example 0.5 for all patches), or if they are reduced independently (for example 0.33 for patch1, 0.52 for patch2, ... )

Comment: (1) the behavior I want is that every tick has a parameter that will affect all patches equally (the simulation starts with an individual value in the patch and in the next ticks there will be this multiplier that will change the values ​​of the patches (for represent an environmental variance, good years and bad years. (2) The prob parameter would be equal to every tick for all patches. For example (patch00) resource value of 38000 and (patch01) of 40000 would both be multiplied by the same parameter value (which I didn't want to be a fractional value...). Thanks for your attention and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have the same value for all patches, you must define a global variable, for example `resource-availability`:

```
globals [resource-availability]
```

Each simulation set, the `resource-availability` will be set to a random value between 0 and 1:

```
to set-resource-availability
 set resource-availability random-float 1
end
```

Because you want the turtles to not have fractional values as `resource-turtle`, you must round `resources * resource-availability` in someway, using `ceiling`, `floor` or `round`.

In the following example, I used `ceiling`:

```
globals [resource-availability]
turtles-own [ metabolism resource-turtle ]
patches-own [ resources ]

to setup
 ca
  reset-ticks
  ask n-of 2 patches  [sprout 1 [ setup-turtles ] ]
  setup-patches
end

to setup-patches
  ask patches 
  [ 
    set resources random 50 + 50
  ]
end

to setup-turtles
  set metabolism 4
  set resource-turtle [ resources ] of patch-here
end

to go
  set-resource-availability
  ask turtles 
  [
    turtle-eat
  ]
  tick
end

to turtle-eat
 set resource-turtle (ceiling(resources * resource-availability) - metabolism )
end

to set-resource-availability
 set resource-availability random-float 1
end
```

Comment: Lena, thank you very much, your form is much more efficient than I had managed. I had changed the value of the patch, that is, every tick changed the values ​​of all the patches, but this way it is more efficient, because only the turtle patch changes. Thank you :)